# Cómo puedo eliminar 5 caracteres o cierta cantidad de caracteres al final de un string en PHP?

Tags: php, string

Mi problema es que tengo el siguiente string:

```
abcdefghijk
```

y me gustaría que el string quedara como:

```
abcdef
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo en PHP?

Comment: Hola @Andrés. Está claro el objetivo, pero no queda claro cómo es que estás queriendo hacerlo. Es decir, ¿Te interesa quedarte con los primeros 6 caracteres? ¿O eliminar los últimos 5? ¿O quedarte con la mitad del largo del string? ¿O los caracteres menores a `f`? ¿O los caracteres hexadecimales? ¿O hasta las primeras 4 consonantes? ¿O buscar un texto específico dentro de otro? ¿O desde una posición x hasta una posición y, calculada en el código? ¿O los caracteres que podrían escribirse con la mano izquierda en el teclado? ... Quizás te sea útil leer [ask].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sólo necesitas hacer uso de la función [substr()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php), por lo que podrías igualar una variable a esta y que te quede así:

```
$cadena = substr("abcdefghijk", 0, -5)
```

y eso te devolverá la cadena que deseas, en este caso `"abcdef"`.

Por si te sirve, te dejo esta página donde puedes ver los demás usos de `subtstr`: [php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php](http://php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta y la edición me fueron muy útiles.

Comment: @AndrésBustamante si esta respuesta ayudó a solucionar el problema de tu pregunta, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) haciendo click en el **✔️**, que está bajo las flechas de votación, a la izquierda de la misma... De lo contrario, quizás deberías [editar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/31249/edit) tu pregunta para aclarar el problema.